# Is it safe to use '&&' to combine 2 conditions?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I want to test 2 conditions in order to execute some code.
The 2 conditions are the existence of `@page` and `@page.content`

Obviously `@page.content` would not exist if `@page` does not in the first place. Worst it will give me an exception if `@page` is `nil` since `content` does not exist for `nil` class

So finally my question is: Is it always safe to specify the conditions as `if @page && @page.content`?

Or should we make sure to break them into two lines as

```
if @page
  if @page.content
  ...
```

Since the interpreter (or the compiled code in other languages) may evaluate the second condition (`@page.content`) before the first one (`@page`)

Thanks for your clarifications !

Comment: If you have `@page && @page.content` then it will never evaluate `@page.content` if `@page` is nil/false.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Are you asking whether `a && b` always evaluates `a` and does a shortcut? Is that your point? If so, only focus on that. Your question is scattered and includes too much noise.

Comment: No that's not my point ! Re-read the question and you'll get it...

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're misunderstanding the way boolean conditions are evaluated. It is pretty strict:

- The expression is evaluated from **left to right**.
- If any condition fails, the rest is **ignored**.

That means in the case of:

```
if (@page && @page.content)
```

If `@page` is not logically true, that is, is `false` or `nil`, then evaluation halts there. `@page.content` is not called.

This is called [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and is a pretty standard feature in most programming languages.

There are other ways of adding the same logic. In Ruby you can do this:

```
@page.try(:content)
```

That has the effect of calling `content` if and only if `@page` is present.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use `if @page && @page.content` because the first portion of the if statement, whether @page exist, will be determined first. If it doesn't, the whole statement will fail and `@page.content` will never be evaluated. You don't have to worry about throwing an error with @page being nil.